# Compiling a cabal project with LLVM on GHC 7.10 RC1

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I've tried:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies -w /usr/local/bin/ghc-7.10.0.20141222  --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks --ghc-option=-fllvm --ghc-option=-static
$ cabal configure -w /usr/local/bin/ghc-7.10.0.20141222  --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks --ghc-option=-fllvm --ghc-option=-static
$ cabal build   
Building unagi-chan-0.3.0.0...
Preprocessing library unagi-chan-0.3.0.0...

when making flags consistent: Warning:
    Using native code generator rather than LLVM, as LLVM is incompatible with -fPIC and -dynamic on this platform
```

I don't see anything referencing "PIC" in the output of `cabal build -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I needed `--disable-shared`:

```
cabal configure -w /usr/local/bin/ghc-7.10.0.20141222  --enable-tests --enable-benchmarks --ghc-option=-fllvm --ghc-option=-static --disable-shared
```